# How to get the specific tab to be accessed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

in my script , I am attempting the execute my code on a specific tab. 
Here is my code snippet

```
function sendalert() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

My google sheet has 6 tabs, but I would like my script to run always on the tab named "Operator". How do I enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the script for the sheet with the sheet name of `Operator` in the active Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to access to the specific sheet using the sheet name, you can use `getSheetByName(name)`.
- When `getActiveSheet()` is used, the opened sheet in the browser is used. If the browser is not opened, the sheet of 1st tab is used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
function sendalert() {
  var sheetName = "Operator";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // do something.

}
```

#### References:

- [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)